# How to add items to list in c# dynamically

Tags: c#, list, asp.net-mvc-4

Hi I am developing one mvc4 application. I came across one scenario where i want to add items ti list. I have one foreach loop inside that i have one list. 
This is my code.

```
foreach (var indId in myuploadId)
{
   List<emailClass> getemailDetails = objBAL.getemailDetails(indId);
   List<emailClass> obj = new List<emailClass>();
   obj.AddRange(getemailDetails);
}
```

This is my code snippet. getemailDetails method will take some data from database and add it to obj list. On second iteration of foreach loop it gets corresponding data from database and add it to obj but here I am facing problem. Whenever i add second item to obj my first item gets disappear. Can someone tell me how can i retain information in list? Thank you.

Comment: Declare the lists outside of the loop.

Comment: List<emailClass> obj = new List<emailClass>(); take outside the loop.

Comment: By initiating your list ```obj``` in each loop, you will "reset" it. It will nether contain more than one element and it's not available outside your loop due to it's scope

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to move the declaration of the lists outside of the loop. At the moment on each loop a new list is created and the old one is lost.

Change your code to look like the below, see that the lists are outside the loop so they get re-used each time rather than replaced.

```
List<emailClass> getemailDetails = new List<emailClass>();
List<emailClass> obj = new List<emailClass>();

foreach (var indId in myuploadId)
{
    getemailDetails = objBAL.getemailDetails(indId);
    obj.AddRange(getemailDetails);
}
```

Comment: No problem, glad to help. Please accept if/when you have time :-)

Comment: Thanks. Stackover flow said me you cant make as answer within 4 miniutes